# Grails debugging flash scope

Tags: debugging, authentication, grails, grails-plugin

I am using [Authentication plugin](http://www.grails.org/Authentication+Plugin) for Grails. It needs a flash variable to be set to do redirection after successful login.

I set the flash variable in various places in controller, in view just before authentication service does it's work, but somehow flash variables are being cleared on the way.

I can't manage to find a way to spot the request that clears flash scope. I am asking some advice on how to find the point that flash is being cleared so I may have better idea on what to do.

Of course answers on how to fix the problem with Authentication plugin are even more appreciated.

Comment: We need more details about your case before we can answer. My guess is that you have a redirect somewhere in your controllers that's clearing the flash variables before they hit the plugin controller

Answer (score 0):

which authentication plugin, there are many.

Debugging things like this is a pain. I would attach the source of the plugin into your IDE, fire up your debugger, and step thru the plugin execution.

Comment: I already gave link to plugin in my question. As I stated in my question flash variables are cleared before plugin wants to use them. I found out this by editing plugin and logging flash variables.